# Rest Service with optional Facades/API's

Tags: java, rest, netbeans, architecture

I am working on building a Restful Web Service in Java and it came to light yesterday that they want to have `"pluggable"/optional components/api's` that may be mixed and matched to make a webservice that offers different options to different people(different installs).

I am using `Java/Netbeans/Tomee`.  We are quite far along now and pulling it apart is going to be a bit painful but I thought I might ask here how I may have designed it had I known this in the beginning.

So, basically if I have facades X,Y,Z they want to potentially be able to install only X and Z and not have any of the functionality of Y present in the install.  They do not just want Y disabled which would be too simple. Problem is since this was not a requirement in the beginning Y is not easily removable because it is tied into Factory Pattern code for DAO.

Any suggestions on possible design decisions in the beginning that would have made this simple?

Comment: Any possibility you can format your post, put some nice pictures, so users don't read for the heck of it.

Comment: @Gee_Reg Are these components about additional business features, or are they cross-cutting affordances (for sorting, querying, etc.) that you want to be pluggable in any part of the REST API ?

Comment: They are different business features yes.... and customers may pick and choose the ones they want to pay for and only those would be made available on that custom customer install.. This is not the way it started out, it started out as you would get them all and maybe we would disable some